# Does changing flush.size of the Confluent s3 sink invalidate EOS?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka Connect cluster running the Confluent s3 Sink Connector, configured for EOS.

Our current `flush.size` is set to a rather high number which was ideal for reading in historical data. After having caught up to the current upstream, this high value obviously causes high latency in transferring the records.

I don't see a reason why - all other things being equal, changing the `flush.size` should invalidate EOS. It perhaps wouldn't be "exactly-once" in the meta-sense that the files would not look exactly the same if I were to restart from the beginning, but I don't see a reason why the actual file content would be impacted in this case. However, with cases such as these the devil is often in the details...

I do have some ways to check this, but it would entail a lot more work in identifying and cleaning up the duplicates since there are no automatic processes in place at the moment (under the verified assumption that the connector provides EOS).

Am I wrong? Would changing (only) `flush.size` invalidate EOS?

Comment: FWIW, I asked the question on the [Confluent forums](https://forum.confluent.io/t/does-changing-flush-size-of-the-confluent-s3-sink-invalidate-eos/6890) (which I perhaps should've started with). I'll link back an answer or delete this one if there's any feedback.

Comment: Either the batch is written or it is not. How would that invalidate exactly once? If you change the size, it only affects files written from the last committed offset, and doesn't override existing files.

Comment: Well, that's my reasoning too, but I wanted to make sure I didn't miss any specifics. I would rather ask a dumb question and be 100% sure than run into an unexpected situation because my assumptions are faulty.